# Can each Iteration of a for loop/for_each be done in parallel? (C++11)

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11, parallel-processing, future

I'm iterating over a vector of structs and processing each struct individually.
It looks something like this:

```
for_each(begin(data),end(data),DoTask);
//assume "data" is std::vector<DataT>  
//assume DoTask is a function that takes a DataT by reference
```

The code is significantly slow because DoTask connects to particular websites and analyzes HTML.
What would be the best way to speed this up?
My goal is to analyze multiple DataTs at the same time.
I'm very new to threading, but [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) look promising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
for(T& d : data) std::thread(DoTask, d).detach();
```

Or you can use something more complicated like Intel's Thread Building Blocks and the `parallel_for` (isn't that the name?) function thereof.

Comment: -1 the example will be totally synchronous as the destructor of the `std::future` created from `std::async` will block, in addition this offers no workstealing etc. On should really go with concurrency library.

Comment: @bamboon you're right, I hadn't though of the destructors of the `future`s, good point. My understanding of the threading library did not encompass futures when I wrote this answer. I have amended it to be correct, I think. And the OP did not require workstealing.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using GCC?  Recent versions have a parallel version of `for_each` (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) for how to use it).

Answer (score 3):

You can always use [The Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) from Microsoft, if you target Windows/VS2010 (or later). It has `parallel_for_each`:

```
parallel_for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [] (int& value)
{
  value *= 2;
});
```