# "No Matching for Call to" and "Template Argument Deduction/Substitution Failed" Error in Boost::bind (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I am a complete beginner in using Boost, and I would like to multithread a certain function defined as (I have been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785060/how-can-i-parallelize-a-for-using-boost) thread in defining this function),

```
void function(size_t thread, size_t start_index, size_t sub_length, std::vector<double> vector, double** array, std::vector<std::string> list, std::vector<double> results) {
    double value;
    std::string line, buffer;

    size_t end_index = start_index + sub_length;

    for (size_t i = start_index; i < end_index; i++) {
        int index = vector.at(i);

        if (array[0][index] == -9999.0 || array[1][index] == -9999.0) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            std::ofstream output_file("input_thread_" + std::to_string(thread) + ".inp");
            output_file << std::to_string(array[0][index]) << "\n";          
            output_file << std::to_string(array[1][index]) << "\n";
            output_file.close();

            boost::process::system("sample_executable.exe", boost::process::std_in < "input_thread_" + std::to_string(thread) + ".inp", boost::process::std_out > "output_thread_" + std::to_string(thread) + ".out");

            std::ifstream input_file("output_thread_" + std::to_string(thread) + ".out");

            while (std::getline(input_file, line)) {
                if (line.find("Output") != std::string::npos) {
                    std::istringstream iss(line);
                    iss >> buffer >> value;
                    results.at(i) = value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `results` vector is my desired output of the function, and the desired output of the main script. I then call this function with,

```
double** array;
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::vector<double> vector, results;
std::vector<std::string> list;
size_t sub_length = 500 / 20;
size_t start_index = i * sub_length;

for (size_t i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    list.push_back(std::string(argv[i]));
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    vector.push_back(any_random_number);
}

array = new double*[2];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    array[i] = new double[500];
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    array[0][i] = any_random_number;
    array[1][i] = any_random_number;
}

// initializes the results vector
for (size_t i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
     results.push_back(-9999.0);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    threads.emplace(boost::bind(function, i, start_index, sub_length, vector, array, list, results));
}

for (auto& th : threads) {
    th.join();
}
```

where `array` is a two-dimensional matrix. All the variables are declared and initialized in the main script.

Upon compilation, I receive this error:

```
function_name.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
function_name.cpp:254:151: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<boost::thread>::emplace(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, std::vector<double>, double**, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<double>), boost::_bi::list7<boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> >, boost::_bi::value<double**>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> > > >)’
   threads.emplace(boost::bind(function, i, start_index, sub_length, vector, array, list, results));
                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /share/hpcc/CPU/gcc/8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/vector:64,
                 from /share/hpcc/CPU/gcc/8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /share/hpcc/CPU/gcc/8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/random:49,
                 from function_name.cpp:8:
/share/hpcc/CPU/gcc/8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1135:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Tp = boost::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::thread>]’
  emplace(const_iterator __position, _Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~
/share/hpcc/CPU/gcc/8.4.0/include/c++/8.4.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1135:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
function_name.cpp:254:39: note:   cannot convert ‘boost::bind(R (*)(B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7), A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7) [with R = void; B1 = long unsigned int; B2 = long unsigned int; B3 = long unsigned int; B4 = std::vector<double>; B5 = double**; B6 = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; B7 = std::vector<double>; A1 = long unsigned int; A2 = long unsigned int; A3 = long unsigned int; A4 = std::vector<double>; A5 = double**; A6 = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; A7 = std::vector<double>; typename boost::_bi::list_av_7<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7>::type = boost::_bi::list7<boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> >, boost::_bi::value<double**>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> > >](i, start_index, sub_length, std::vector<double>(vector), array, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >(list), std::vector<double>(results))’ (type ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, std::vector<double>, double**, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<double>), boost::_bi::list7<boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> >, boost::_bi::value<double**>, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::_bi::value<std::vector<double> > > >’) to type ‘std::vector<boost::thread>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::thread*, std::vector<boost::thread> >’}
   threads.emplace(boost::bind(function, i, start_index, sub_length, vector, array, list, results));
                            ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Most of the posts I see regarding this error concerns member functions and templated functions, so I suspect that this might just be a simple fix that I do not know of.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. At a minimum, add declarations for all of the variables and the full error.

Comment: @jisrael18 I have included a minimal example and the full error.

Comment: There is difference between `emplace` and `emplace_back`. I guess you want to use the latter.

Comment: @rafix07 Thank you! It did work. But may I know how? Is it just because of a missing position argument when using `emplace`?

Comment: Sorry. I probably should have caught that even without the additions you made. Yes, it is because the `emplace` method requires the position argument. You also could have resolved the issue by using `emplace` and adding an iterator argument to the `boost::bind` call (`emplace_back` is probably the better solution if you're appending).